# When we create Email case, Can we fire trigger on Case object and Change the Task's Custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

When we create Email case, Can we fire trigger on Case object and Change the Task's Custom field..
I have a custom field on task object.
Whenever, there is a change in Case custom field (Case is created by Email 2 Case), i would like to update the custom field in task.
 Please let me know, to achieve it through trigger ..

Current code:

```
trigger XXX on Case (after insert, after update)
{ 
    List<Task> tskrecords = [Select Id, CustomField, WhatId from Task where WhatId IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()]; 
    for(Task t :tskrecords)
    { 
        if(trigger.isInsert && Trigger.newmap.get(t.WhatId).CustomField == '1234')
        {
            t.CustomField = '5555';
        }
        else if(trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.newmap.get(t.WhatId).CustomField == '1234')
        {
            t.CustomField = '5555';
        }
    } 

    if(tskrecords.size() > 0) 
    {
        update tskrecords; 
    }
}
```

Code is working fine when I manually create / edit the cases through the UI / DataLoader. When I create the case through Email2Case functionality, trigger is not getting fired. Not sure why ? Even the Cases are not getting created when I put the above code in the trigger file. When I remove the code, then the Email2Case functionality works. This is the issue.

Comment: I have used this code - trigger XXX on Case (after insert, after update){ 
List<Task> tskrecords = [Select Id, CustomField, WhatId from Task where WhatId IN : Trigger.newMap.keySet()];
        for(Task t :tskrecords){
            if(trigger.isInsert && Trigger.newmap.get(t.WhatId).CustomField == '1234'){
                t.CustomField = '5555';
            }
            else if(trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.newmap.get(t.WhatId).CustomField == '1234'){
                child.CustomField = '5555';
            }
        }
        if(tskrecords.size() > 0)
            update tskrecords;
}

Comment: What doesn't work with your current solution?  What error message do you get?

Comment: Hi Nick, Code is working fine when I manually create / edit the cases through the UI / DataLoader. When I create the case through Email2Case functionality, trigger is not getting fired. Not sure why ? Even the Cases are not getting created when I put the above code in the trigger file. When I remove the code, then the Email2Case functionality works. This is the issue.

Comment: well, a big problem with that code is the `child.CustomField =...` part. What is `child`?

Comment: Sorry Nick, that will be t.CustomField = '5555'; ... Unknowingly, i wrote child.CustomField ...  My requirement is to update Task Custom Field

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will stop a case from being created.  This is obviously a cut down version of your code.  Are you able to include the complete code?

Comment: Actually, other functionalities are working fine, Code is very huge... Only this functionality is not working ..... If i use it normally without using Email 2 Case, code works fine.... Only when the code is included and I try to create case using email --- (Email2Case OOTB feature ) --- It does not create the case...

Comment: If you don't want to share the code, then it's up to you to isolate the part of the code that is causing issues.  Try progressively removing bits of the code until you find that part that is causing the issue.  Apart from having if statements you don't need, the code you've provided is fine and won't stop a case being created.  You have looked at the logs, right?

Comment: Yah, even i have looked at the logs as well

Comment: i'd be kind of surprised that the Tasks are even created by Email2Case until after the Case before/after triggers are finished as there needs to be a CaseId to attach the Task to. So, updating them might need to be done a @future method